# Delete an array element inside a document with mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm not sure if Ihave to get the document ,change the object an d update it on the database or if I can update the document on one step

on this document:

```
{
"_id":{"$oid":"5fb15c68daa5c11cf5d6d4b3"},"state":[],
"users":[
    {"_id":{"$oid":"5fb15c68daa5c11cf5d6d4b4"},"user":{"$oid":"5f81eb91d537dc3baf443a84"},"calification":0},
    {"_id":{"$oid":"5fb15c9cdaa5c11cf5d6d4b5"},"user":{"$oid":"5fa6f98f15e96c1125b905a9"},"calification":0}
],
"test":{"$oid":"5f986af2baa88b2d30760961"},
"__v":1}
```

I know the document id and the users array element id, its possible to delete it in one query?

**UPDATE:**

I'm using , this code but nothing its done

```
Game.update({
      "_id": req.body.game_id,
    },
    {
      "$pull": {
        "users": {
          "user": '5f81eb91d537dc3baf443a84'
        }
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do in one query.

If I've not missunderstood the question, you only need this:

```js
db.collection.update({
  "_id": document_id,
},
{
  "$pull": {
    "users": {
      "_id": user_id_to_remove
    }
  }
})
```

You look for the document and then `$pull` the element which has `_id` 1 (or whatever you want).

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/srg4D3s_nGa)

Note that you can use `user` field if you want instead of `_id`.

Comment: I tried , but nothing its deleted from the array, I have updated the first post